# Segmentation Fault when I add a for Loop

Tags: c, string, parsing, memory, fault

When I add the for loop I get segmentation fault. Also, when I add buffer[i] !='\0' in the while loop condition, I get segmentation fault error. I am having a hard time trying to understand why this error pops up. Thanks.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[2000] = "-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp 614400 Oct 18  2006\r\n"
    char String[2000];
    int i, j, k= 0;
    int nextline= 0;

   for(k = 0; k<strlen(buffer);k++)
    {
        while((buffer[i] != '\r' && buffer[i+1] != '\n'))
         {
           String[j] = buffer[i];
           i++;
           j++;
         }

   }
  printf("%s", String);               
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be initializing `i` and `j` anywhere before using them.

Comment: Joachim is right, "int i, j, k = 0" initializes only k to zero.

Comment: No semi-colon after buffer initialization.

Comment: And I don't know if String is keyword in that situation.

Comment: As pointed out by Joachim, `i` and `j` are used uninitialized, and your `while` is an infinite loop (there is no `\r` nor `\n` in your `buffer`).

Comment: `CR LF` (Dos) and `LF` (Unix) are not the only two line terminations.  You could also have just `CR` (classic Mac operating system), and IIRC, `LF CR` is also a possibility.  In general, you should look for either `CR` or `LF`, and if it is immediately followed by the other code, consume both characters and emit the new line character.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to put the '\r\n'. It was in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loop of the form `for(k=0; k < strlen(buffer); k++) { ... }` is generally very bad code.  It is O(n²), meaning that the time for the loop increases quadradically as n increases.  Why?  Each pass through the loop, the `strlen` function is called to determine the length of the string in `buffer`.  If the string is 1000 character long, each `strlen` internally loops 1000 times, and it itself is called 1000 times, for 1000000 iterations of the inner loop!  Instead, the length of the string should be calculated once, outside the loop.  Eg)

```
int buffer_len = strlen(buffer);
for(k=0; k<buffer_len; k++) { ... }
```

You could also use a `char *` as your loop index, and loop until you encounter the null character:

```
for(char *c_ptr = buffer; *c_ptr != '\0'; *c_ptr++) { ... }
```

---

At any rate, for your problem, you do not need the double loop:

```
for(k = 0; k < strlen(buffer); k++)
{
    // ...
    while( /* incorrect condition here */ ) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

The above suggests you want to loop through each character in your string, and then starting at each of those characters, perform another inner loop.  What you ***probably*** want is just an `if( )` statement:

```
for(k = 0; k < strlen(buffer); k++)
{
    // ...
    if( buffer[k] == '\r'  &&  buffer[k+1] == '\n' ) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

I'll leave you to struggle with what goes in the `// ...` comments, if anything.  You learn more by doing.

As others have pointed out, your `i` & `j` variables were left uninitialized.  You will want to ensure you initialize them properly before using them.  You did initialize `k` to zero, which was actually unnecessary since the `for(k=0; ... ; ...)` loop is already initializing the value of `k`.